# После обновления страницы выводится надпись

Tags: php, html

Обновляю страницу и появляется надпись `Hello`, которая должна была появится после нажатия на кнопку.
В чем может быть проблема?
Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['indexx']))
{echo "Hello";}
?>
<from action="php2.php" method="POST">
<hr>
 <p>
 <button type="submit" name="indexx">+++++</button>
 </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: когда вы обновляете страницу, то форма отправляется повторно. обычно браузер об этом предупреждает. При самом то нажатии кнопки, показывается это слово?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имя формы должна быть не **from** а **form**

Также добавьте закрывающий тег формы чтобы `button` был внутри него

Comment: тоже самое получается после обновления

Comment: @Даня скажите имя файла с которого вы запускаете данный скрипт

Comment: в action все правильно, имя файла php2.php

Comment: @Даня у вас что то с именем файла потому что данный код у меня сработал я только изменил у вас имя формы и добавил кнопку внутрь формы.Посмотрите повнимательнее

Comment: У вас при обновлены страницы на f5. Всплывает такой текст "На странице, которую вы ищете, использовалась введенная вами информация. При возврате на эту страницу может потребоваться повторить выполненные ранее действия. Продолжить?"

Comment: @Даня  вы уже один или несколько раз запускали данный скрипт  потому и он выводит так.Перезапустите ваш сервер очистите кеш (либо откройте с другого браузера) и повторите с изменениями которое я дал.Если будет удачно не забудьте принять мой ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['indexx']))
        {echo "Hello";}
        ?>
        <form action="php2.php" method="POST">
            <hr>
            <p>
            <button type="submit" name="indexx" value="+++++">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```